# Using 2 versions of log4net in one application

Tags: log4net-configuration

I have a need to reference 2 different versions of log4net in my application.
An older assembly I am referencing uses log4net-net-1.0.dll version 1.2.0.30507,
whereas my newer dependencies use log4net V1.2.15.

I have tried placing this in the web.config to have my application look in a different folder when trying to find the older log4net dll:

```
<runtime>   
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">   
        <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net-net-1.0" publicKeyToken="b4df9eabc7e0e71e" />
        <codeBase version="1.2.0.30507" href="log4netv1.2.0\log4net-net-1.0.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>  
    </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

But the dll is not getting found.
Is there something else I need to do in order for this to work.